# android- activity show first instead of splash screen

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm making a splash screen for my aplication .I want a welcome screen shows when application opens .

This is the code ,I used MainActivity as a splashscreen (I'm just testing)

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // TODO: Your application init goes here.
            Intent mInHome = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FistActiivty.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(mInHome);
            MainActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }, 4000);
}
}
```

layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/image"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the manifest ,MainActivity runs first and then goes to FirstActivity class .

When I open the app , this shows first :

[image]

and then splash screen shows :

[image]

Note: It doesn't show firstActivity's layout .it just show an empty layout .

This is the manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.example.test.FistActiivty"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.FistActiivty" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

I test some apps and all of them show the splash screen first

How can I show splash screen first and then show the next activity ?

Comment: are you sure that the first screenshot is really *FirstActivity* ? (add some content in FirstActivity layout to be sure that it is really what you think it is.)

Comment: @ben75 no  , it's not firstactivity's layout . It's just an empty screen

Comment: @stealthjong I edit my post and add manifest

Comment: Is the layout you posted the activity_main layout? Also, you have 2 Launcher activities and no default activity. You probably should have a look at fixing those (which may or may not be unrelated to the problem you're fixing but still should be addressed). To mark your main activity as the default, put this in your MainActivity: <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see before your splashscreen is the default window background displayed during application startup. You can customize this screen from xml if you define a new style and use it in your first activity.

You must define a style using the splashscreen as background:

In res/values/style.xml :

```
<style name="splashScreenStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/image</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

In your manifest : use this style for your Main activity :

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.test.FistActiivty"
    android:theme="@style/splashScreenStyle"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

There is no need for two activities. As soon as you `setContent` the window background will be replaced by your layout. i.e. you can drop your MainActivity and clean-up your manifest (it should not contains two android.intent.category.LAUNCHER)

Comment: Thanks , it works fine . The only problem is that the actionbar is showing , I hide it on activity "getSupportActionBar().hide();" but how can I hide it in the default display screen ?

Comment: @mahdiyamani you can configure the splashScreenStyle. see my edit.